# Refer other properties in Spring expression language

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have a field as shown below which works

```
@Value("#{T(java.util.regex.Pattern).compile('[0-9]+')}")
private Pattern myPattern;
```

But if I change it to

```
@Value("#{T(java.util.regex.Pattern).compile(${myProp})}")
private Pattern myPattern;
```

it does not work. Is there a way to refer properties inside Spring expression?

Comment: Did you configure the **myprop** in your context.xml file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479156/why-would-spring-be-trying-to-use-the-properties-variable-reference-string-inste?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I would guess that the `'`s are the problem.
I would expect that SpEL handle `'${myProp}'` as a string but not as a property.</strike>

Therefore I would try to remove the `'`s

See my last comment

> I have had a look at my code and found this:
>
> @Value("#{new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').parse('${showAfterDate}')}")
>
> -- So '${myProp}' should work

Comment: That expression is not been possible because of the second curly brace.

Comment: you are right - I have had a look at my code and found this:  `@Value("#{new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').parse('${showAfterDate}')}")` -- So `'${myProp}'` should work

Comment: Oh crap! ​It worked this time. How is it able to parse the second curly brace now!